# Change Image in dropdown menu on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have got a dropdown menu , what i want is to show image on right side of the dropdown menu when the link is hovered , every link will have a different image , so when the link is hover the image should change automatically and when there is no hover effect it should go back to one fixed image.

Any ideas on how to get this effect working

In this Section:

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="left-menu-section">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="right-menu-image-section">
<img src="" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to show images in the right section when the mouse is hovered on to the links provided in the left section.
Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: to be honest i was not able to get this working using jquery.hover , cant change the images dynamically

Answer (score -1):

```
$img = $(".right-menu-image-section img");

var old_img = $img.attr('src');

$(".left-menu-section li").hover(function(){
    // need to implement some logic for getting new image
    // set new image
    $img.attr(src, new_img);
}, function(){
    // reset the original image
    $img.attr(src, old_img);
});
```